# UI Button to another view controller

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm very new to ios programming and I wanted to ask how to use a UI button to redirect to another view controller. Sorry if my question sounds stupid, I'm just getting started with ios programming :)

[2 view controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfL2L.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate from the First view controller where the button is present to the second view controller then,

1. Embed the first view controller in the `UINavigationController`.
   Just click on the first view controller -> Go to editor on the tool bar -> Embed In -> Navigation controller. So this makes the first view controller as your base or your root.
2. Now just click on the button and make a right click action from the button to the second view controller. So it gives you an option as shown below:
   [image: When you click on the button and drag it toward your second view controller]
3. Then, just click on the 'Show' option, so it shows a link between your first and second controller:
   [image: Once you click on the show option]

Just run the application, and you are good to go.

**Note:** If you don't embed the first view controller in the navigation controller, the it won't show a navigation behaviour, but your second view controller will be presented from bottom to top.

And it's okay to ask silly questions as well. Keep learning :)

Comment: Thank you so much! You really helped me a lot! I'll keep learning and pay it forward as soon as I'm a more talented programmer. Thank you again :))